# DataGridView updation of cells

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

In my project, there is a datagridview if there are no data and click on the UPDATE button, I should get error message. Here if I click directly on update button I am getting error message, but if I click on the datagridview ( even though there is no data in the datagridview ) and click on update, I am getting message as updated. Please tell what is code that I should use instead of (dataGridView2.SelectedCells.Count == 0).
The code I am using is:

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (dataGridView2.SelectedCells.Count == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There are no any records to update");
        }
        else
        {
            SqlConnection con = Helper.getconnection();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            string PrjName = txtPrjNmae.Text;
            string Description = txtPrjdescription.Text;
            DateTime Date = dateUpdate.Value;
            dateUpdate.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
            dateUpdate.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yy";
            string Size = txtPrjSize.Text;
            string Manager = txtPrjManager.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "Update Projects set Description='" + Description + "', DateStarted='" + Date + "',TeamSize='" + Size + "',Manager='" + Manager + "' where ProjectName= '" + PrjName + "' ";
            MessageBox.Show("Project Details are updated");
            dataGridView2.Update();
            dataGridView2.Refresh();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
            BindData3();            
    }
```

Comment: What's the `error message`?

Comment: I am sorry, I mean error message is the validation, I should get.

Comment: as of now I am using There are no any records to update". what is the code to be used instead of if (dataGridView2.SelectedCells.Count == 0)
to get the same message, even though datagridview is selected and if there is no data.   Thank you. Sorry for causing confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem here is that you set the `AllowUserToAddRows` property of your `DataGridView` to `true`. In this way there always be an empty row in the bottom of your `DataGridView` so `RowCount` will return almost 1 (the empty row used to create a new entry).

There are almost 2 possibilities to get rid of the problem:

1. Set the `AllowUserToAddRows` to false if you don't want to allow the user to add new rows
2. Change the problem in this way:

.

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (dataGridView2.SelectedCells.Count == 0 || dataGridView2.RowCount <= 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There are no any records to update");
        }
        else
        {
            SqlConnection con = Helper.getconnection();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            string PrjName = txtPrjNmae.Text;
            string Description = txtPrjdescription.Text;
            DateTime Date = dateUpdate.Value;
            dateUpdate.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
            dateUpdate.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yy";
            string Size = txtPrjSize.Text;
            string Manager = txtPrjManager.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "Update Projects set Description='" + Description + "', DateStarted='" + Date + "',TeamSize='" + Size + "',Manager='" + Manager + "' where ProjectName= '" + PrjName + "' ";
            MessageBox.Show("Project Details are updated");
            dataGridView2.Update();
            dataGridView2.Refresh();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
            BindData3();            
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (dataGridView2.RowCount == 0){
        MessageBox.Show("There are no any records to update");
}
```

Comment: I apologize, it is not working, and it if we use the code I am every time getting the message "Message details are updated" irrespective of selection.

Comment: @karthikreddy of course, it checks only for the `RowCount`, usually your `dataGridView` will get some row so the updating is always performed. Your code in the `else` part doesn't involve to some selected rows, ... why do you want to perform some check other than `RowCount`? I don't get well what you really want. You should make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the following code and see if it works:

```
dataGridView2.RowCount == 0
```